# Как найти второй положительный элемент массива?

Tags: pascal

Надо найти второй положительный элемент массива. Вот мои наработки:

```
program summa;
var
  a: array [1..100] of integer;
  i, sum, n: integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  Write('Введите размер массива: ');
  Readln(n);
  Writeln('Массив:');
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    a[i] := Random(20) - random(17);
    Write(a[i]:4);
  end;
  Writeln;
  sum:=0;
  for i := 1 to n do
///решение
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Создай еще один счетчик до цикла, например j и пока j!=2 ты ищешь это число, когда j==2 запоминаешь число в другой переменной и выводишь его, если по завершению основного цикла j!=2, сообщаешь что положительных чисел либо вообще нет, либо только одно

Comment: блин, не понимаю, можешь код написать?

Comment: @test123 , очень смешно. этот язык я не использовал уже два-три года

Comment: @adam_k, причём тут язык? Да и алгоритм вам уже подсказали... Хоть 10 лет не пишите "на этом языке", не зная синтаксиса ни одного из языков, можете уверено написать на псевдокоде свой вариант решения, и на него с удовольствием ответят здесь. То что вы показали, буквально кричит что вы не хотите разбираться в вопросе, и просите решить всё за вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    program HelloWorld;
var
  a: array [1..100] of integer;
  i, sum, n, k: integer;
begin
  Randomize;
  k:=0;sum:=0;
  Write('Введите размер массива: ');
  Readln(n);
  Writeln('Массив:');
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    a[i] := Random(0) - random(20);
    if a[i] > 0 then begin inc(k);
    if k = 2 then sum := a[i]; end;
    Write(a[i]:4);
  end;
  writeln;
  case k of
      0: Writeln('Нет положительных элементов');
      1: Writeln('Нет второго положительного элемента');
      else Writeln('Второй положительный элемент : ',sum);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: При `n` больше 100 будет плохо

Comment: Почему? Пускай наложит условия на  `n` или же с ними

Comment: Если звезды сложатся так, что в массиве окажется только один положительный элемент (или вовсе ни одного), то получится тоже не очень хорошо. :)

Comment: Покажет ему 0, а 0 - не положительный, не отрицательниый. )

Comment: А в разве паскале неинициализированные явно переменные всегда инициализируются нулем? Я вот такого не помню, и подозреваю, что это может зависит от компилятора и от его настроек оптимизации.